# Do valve cover gaskets need to be replaced every time you reopen the valve cover?

Tags: valve, gasket, valve-cover

About two weeks ago, I replaced my cork/rubber valve cover gaskets on my 84 2.8L V6 Ranger since the old ones were leaking pretty badly. I forgot to adjust the valves when I did the gaskets, and now I'm thinking it should be done.

Do they need to be changed again or can I just reuse the old gaskets? I didn't use any type of sealant, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally:

- Cork - always replace. (this includes rubber covered cork)
- Rubber - replace if deformed or damaged.

On newer vehicles with the molded rubber ones which fit into a slot (I've seen on valve covers, intake manifold runners, etc, etc, etc) are good as long as they are pliable (still feel soft/subtle ... not hard or brittle) and are not damaged. So much better than cork.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no issue in reusing new rubber valve cover gaskets.

I don't have experience with cork gaskets, but assuming they don't permanently deform under load then even these should be reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only a few weeks old and you didn't use sealant, you should be able to reuse them.

Usually I would replace a cork one but since they are so new, I would just check them for any damage from removal and reuse them if not.

Damage usually comes from drying out and overheating but you shouldn't have problems with either.

Answer (score 0):

I reused cork gaskets many times on my own Olds V-8. I used sealant only on the cover side and removed and replaced carefully. I checked and adjusted the clearance frequently with solid lifters. However , if this is a one time thing , get new gaskets.